# Местонахождение переменной

Tags: javascript

внутри let работает не корректно(после каждого нажатия let left и let top ставит 0) снаружи вообще не работает, есть какой  вариант?

```js
let left = 0;
let top = 0;

window.onkeydown = function move_left() {
  if(event.keyCode == 37) {
    left = left - 10;
    document.querySelector('.person').style.left = left+'px';
  } else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
    left = left + 10;
    document.querySelector('.person').style.left = left+'px';
  }
  
  if(event.keyCode == 38) {
    top = top - 10;
    document.querySelector('.person').style.top = top+'px';
  } else if(event.keyCode == 40) {
    top = top + 10;
    document.querySelector('.person').style.top = top+'px';
  }
};
```

```css
.person {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">1</div>
```

Comment: У вас есть снаружи переменная, со значением 0, вы её переписываете внутри со значением 0.. Не переменная работает не правильно..

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я это для примера сделал, чтобы было понятно что и так и так не работает

Comment: Прикольно, и тут, и на jsFiddle, какая-то проблема конкретно с названием top) Если назвать по другому, работает. Или завернуть в IIFE, `(function() { /* здесь код */ })();`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME дублируйте свой ответ в "Отправить ответ" чтобы я мог принять ваш ответ

Comment: Проблема c `top` из-за того, что всегда есть глобальная переменная `top`, которая [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализируя [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) "вначале" вы получите ошибку [`SyntaxError: redeclaration of formal parameter "x"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Redeclared_parameter), чтобы её обойти вы можете:

1. Инициализировать переменные через [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var);
2. Выполнять скрипт в [самовыполняющейся функции](https://webformyself.com/anonimnye-i-samovypolnyayushhiesya-funkcii-v-javascript/):

```js
(function() {
  let left = 0;
  let top = 0;

  window.onkeydown = function move_left() {
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {
     left = left - 10;
     document.querySelector('.person').style.left = left+'px';
    } else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
      left = left + 10;
      document.querySelector('.person').style.left = left+'px';
    }

    if(event.keyCode == 38) {
      top = top - 10;
      document.querySelector('.person').style.top = top+'px';
    } else if(event.keyCode == 40) {
      top = top + 10;
      document.querySelector('.person').style.top = top+'px';
    }
  };
})();
```

```css
.person {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">1</div>
```

3. Использовать массив:

```js
let param = {
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  };

window.onkeydown = function move_left() {
  if(event.keyCode == 37) {
   param.left = param.left - 10;
   document.querySelector('.person').style.left = param.left+'px';
  } else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
    param.left = param.left + 10;
    document.querySelector('.person').style.left = param.left+'px';
  }

  if(event.keyCode == 38) {
    param.top = param.top - 10;
    document.querySelector('.person').style.top = param.top+'px';
  } else if(event.keyCode == 40) {
    param.top = param.top + 10;
    document.querySelector('.person').style.top = param.top+'px';
  }
};
```

```css
.person {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">1</div>
```

Comment: В случае с `top` глобальная декларация с `var` не пройдёт: в strict mode будет ошибка `TypeError: Cannot set property top of #<Window> which has only a getter`, в sloppy mode переменная просто не изменит глобальную переменную [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top).

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, точно, тогда думаю лучше использовать массив)